# Property Id cannot be empty aws cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

---

```
  NotifierRule:
    Type: "AWS::Events::Rule"
    Properties:
      Description: "Instance state change trigger for EC2 and RDS."
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - "aws.ec2"
        detail-type:
          - "EC2 Instance State-change Notification"
        detail:
          state:
            - "shutting-down"
            - "stopped"
            - "stopping"
            - "terminated"
          instance-id: !Ref EC2Instances
      Name: "InstanceHealthState-Monitoring-Rule"
      State: "ENABLED"
      Targets:
        - Arn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - "LambdaNotifier"
              - "Arn"
```

I'm getting `Property Id cannot be empty` when deploying above stack. Error is from NotifierRule resource. I don't fing any Id attribute in the template. Please help.

Comment: Did you truncate the bottom part of your `Targets`? `Id` is required for `Targets`. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-events-rule-target.html

Comment: No. I didn't. I missed that one. Now that my stack is deployed successfully, lambda functions are not getting executed. It's showing FailedInvocation.

Comment: Did the `Id` suggestion solve the error `Property Id cannot be empty`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that Id is a parameter for Target item.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-events-rule-target.html#cfn-events-rule-target-arn

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/394800) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)